# how to call a javascript function inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

Please, i need to include an iframe in an html document, but need also to push a variable from a Js function  located on the same page (which retrieve cookies values)

```
<script type=text/JavaScript>
var generateLinkerUrl = function(url){ etc...
  </script>
<body>

<iframe src=
var newUrl =
generateLinkerUrl("http://blog.domain.com/mypage.php") // url of the iframe </iframe>`
```

Is the call to the Js function inside the  tag correct or do i need something else to add  ?

Many tks..

Comment: does your page also sit on blog.domain.com? because if not, you don't get access to the iframe contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a javscript function inside an iframe tag like it looks like you are attempting.  It is not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish, but here is some info:

If the iframe is not on the same domain as the host document, then the browser will block all direct javascript access between the two except for cooperating communication using `[window.postMessage()][1]`.

If the iframe is on the same domain as the host document, then you can reach inside the document of the iframe like this:

```
// iframe is the DOM element of the iframe from the host document
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

Then, from that, you can get to the window which lets you get to global javascript variables or functions.

Putting that all together, you could call a function in an iframe on the same domain like this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myIframe");
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var iframeWindow = iframeDocument.window;

// call function in the iFrame
iframeWindow.funcIniFrame("xxx");
```

---

If, what you're really trying to do is to have an iframe with a `.src` attribute that is generated from the host document, you can do that like this and there are no domain restrictions for this type of setting:

```
<iframe id="myIFrame"></iframe>

<script>
document.getElementById("myIFrame").src = generateLinkerUrl("http://blog.domain.com/mypage.php");
</script>
```